# Why there is error message about "__int64" when it's not even used in my code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, types, int64

I wrote the code below:

```
#define int64_t long long int
typedef long long int64_t; //this line is line 2
void main()
{
int64_t a;
}
```

When I complied this program, the compiler displayed an error message: in line 2, '__int64' followed by 'long' is illegal.

But the strange thing is that there is no "__int64" in my code, only "int64_t", but "int64_t" and "__int64" are spelled differently, so they are totally different variables. Yes, it is wired that an error about a variable which never appears in my code occurred. What is wrong about line 2, and how does this line cause this error?

Thank you for reading and hope to receive your valuable answers.

Comment: What are you defining `int64_t` twice? `typedef long long long long int;` is indeed illegal, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: marco (line 1) is process before the compilation, it will simply replace every `int64_t` by `long long int`. So, has @Quimby said, you go  `long long long long int;` which is illegal.

Comment: Macros a simple text-replacements in the code. With your macro the statement `typedef long long int64_t;` will become `typedef long long long long int;`. Which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: With that said, I'm not sure you're allowed to redefine the *standard* symbol `int64_t`. C and C++ might be different in this case though (which is why you should almost never tag multiple *different* languages).

Comment: `long long long long int;` That'd be one big mother of a integer. I'm hoping for at least 256 bits.

Comment: Why do you manually define `int64_t`? Include `<cstdint>` (or `<stdint.h>` in C) to let the compiler define it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong about line 2. The problem is line 1 and line 2 together. Based on your previous question about a similar situation, I would guess that you don't know how macros work.

Answer (score 8):

Back before the C++ standard added `long long` as a standard type with a minimum of 64 bits, Microsoft added a type named `__int64` to their compiler to provide the same basic capability, but with a name that was a conforming extension to C (i.e., names starting with an underscore followed by another underscore or an upper-case letter are reserved for the implementation).

When the C++ committee got around to adding `long long` to C++, Microsoft seems to have implemented it as an alias for their existing `__int64` type. So, when you use `long long`, the compiler internally "thinks" of that as meaning `__int64`.

In your code, after the macro is expanded, you have:

```
typedef long long long long int;
```

In parsing this the compiler treats the first `long long` as meaning `__int64`. That's then followed by another `long`, and parsing fails. When it prints out the error message, it prints out `long long` using its internal name for that 64-bit type (`__int64`).